# incorrect syntax near keyword where

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GradeTable(Grade,UserID,RegDate)Values('" & TxtGrade.Text.Trim & "','" & UserID & "','" & DTBReg.Value & "'Where GradeTable.StudentID ='" & StudentID & "' and GradeTable.CourseID= '" & CourseID & "') "
```

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/ This is a textbook example of sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: This is not a question, this is code.

Comment: why are you using a where clause in your insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems for what you are trying to do, that what you need is an UPDATE statement and not an INSERT as you are writing. This seems a much more appropiate query:

```
UPDATE GradeTable 
SET Grade = @grade, 
    UserID = @UserID, 
    RegDate = @RegDate 
WHERE StudentID = @StudentID AND CourseID = @CourseID
```

Note that I used parameters and not the value of your textbox. This is because you are being vulnerable to one of the most common database security flaws that is SQL Injection.

Use that text for your query, and then you can add your values to the query this way:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", TxtGrade.Text.Trim);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
//AND SO ON WITH OTHER PARAMETERS
```

Assumming cmd is your `SqlCommand`

Comment: Be careful using AddWithValue in ad hoc queries like this. It can sometimes get the datatype wrong and cause issues. Best to explicitly define the datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ Still a +1 from me!!!

Comment: @SeanLange you are right about that. I just used AddWithValue as I do not know OP tables data types. Good observation.